# mvvm Cross execute methods from a loaded viewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm, tabs, command, mvvmcross

How can I execute methods in a loaded view model?
my strucuture;

```
MainView(TabControl) - MainViewModel
View1(Tab1) - ViewModel1
View2(Tab2) - ViewModel2
View3(Tab3) - ViewModel3
```

Inside every ViewModel there are a ReloadData()-Method, that load some data from my database. They already get fired in the constructor like so;

```
public ViewModel1()
{
   ReloadData();
}

private async void ReloadData(){ }
```

When navigating to the MainViewModel it will directly(in the ViewAppeared-Method) navigate to the tabs;

```
this._navigationService.Navigate<ViewModel1>();
this._navigationService.Navigate<ViewModel2>();
this._navigationService.Navigate<ViewModel3>();
```

I want to use this reloader-implemenation in my WPF project and in my mobile versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could try is using `IMvxMessenger` and publish an event when data needs to be reloaded. The concerning TabViewModels subscribe to that event and call `ReloadData()` when invoked.

Another way I have seen this implemented is like this.
You have a `TabHostViewModel` and its view contains a `TabControl` in which we want to display three tabs: `TabOneViewModel`, `TabTwoViewModel` and `TabThreeViewModel`. All these tab view models implement an `ITabViewModel` interface.
The `TabControl` is a custom implementation of the `Pivot` class which shows the different tab views and also determines whether the tab to which is navigated should be reloaded.

`TabHostViewModel` and `ITabViewModel`:

```
// TabOneViewModel, TabTwoViewModel and TabThreeViewModel should implement this
public interface ITabViewModel 
{
    bool ShouldReloadBeforeShow { get; }
    
    // This method should reload whatever needs to be reloaded in your ViewModel
    void ReloadModel();
}

public class TabHostViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public IList<TabPage> TabPages { get; set;}
    
    public override Task Initialize()
    {
        TabPages = new List<TabPage>
        {
            new TabPage {
                Title = "Tab one",
                ViewModelType = typeof(TabOneViewModel)
            },
            new TabPage {
                Title = "Tab one",
                ViewModelType = typeof(TabTwoViewModel)
            },
            new TabPage {
                Title = "Tab one",
                ViewModelType = typeof(TabThreeViewModel)
            }
        };
    }
}

public class TabPage
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type ViewModelType { get; set; }
    public ITabViewModel ViewModelInstance { get; set; }
}
```

Custom `TabControl` class:

```
public class TabControl : Pivot
{
    private readonly IMvxViewsContainer _mvxViewsContainer;
    private readonly IMvxViewModelLoader _mvxViewModelLoader;
    
    public TabControl()
    {
        Loaded += TabControl_Loaded;
        SelectionChanged += TabControl_SelectionChanged;
        
        _mvxViewsContainer = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
        _mvxViewModelLoader = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
    }
    
    private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedTab = (TabPage) SelectedItem;

        if (selectedTab.ViewModelInstance != null && selectedTab.ViewModelInstance.ShouldReloadBeforeShow)
            selectedTab.ViewModelInstance.ReloadModel();
    }

    private void TabControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            var tabPage = item as TabPage;
            var view = CreateViewByViewModelType(tabPage.ViewModelType);
            var viewModel = CreateViewModelByViewModelType(tabPage.ViewModelType);

            tabPage.ViewModelInstance = viewModel;
            view.ViewModel = viewModel;
            tabPage.View = view;
        }
        
        Loaded -= TabControl_Loaded;
    }
    
    private MvxWindowsView CreateViewByViewModelType(Type viewModelType)
    {
        var viewType = _mvxViewsContainer.GetViewType(viewModelType);
        if (viewType == null)
            throw new MvxException("View Type not found for " + viewModelType);

        var viewObject = Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
        if (viewObject == null)
            throw new MvxException("View not loaded for " + viewType);

        var view = viewObject as IMvxWindowsView;
        if (view == null)
            throw new MvxException("Loaded View is not a IMvxWindowsView " + viewType);

        return view;
    }
    
    public IMvxViewModel CreateViewModelByViewModelType(Type viewModelType)
    {
        var viewModelRequest = new MvxViewModelRequest(viewModelType);
        var viewModel = _mvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel(viewModelRequest, null);
        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

Use the `TabControl` in your `TabHostView`:

```
<controls:TabControl x:Name="TabHostControl" ItemsSource="{Binding TabPages}">
    <controls:TabControl.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:TabControl.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding View}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</controls:TabControl>
```

Note that you need to specify where the tab control is located so you need to also add the following to the `TabHostView`:

`xmlns:controls="using:NAMESPACE_OF_TABCONTROL_HERE"`

Comment: No problem, get back to me if you miss anything.

Comment: ok, iam stuck now. I can't use this because i use a custom region-presenter and [dragablz](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz) in my wpf project. In the droid and ios version it should work, but i need a more general solution. Do you have experience with getting the viewmodel from a **viewmodel-container** and fire the command from there or passing a interface trougth the navigation?

Comment: I have no knowledge of that framework. What you could also try is using `IMvxMessenger` and publish an event when data needs to be reloaded. The concerning TabViewModels subscribe to that event and call `ReloadData()` when invoked.

Comment: Thank you for the tip using `IMvxMessenger`. It works perfectly while communicating between loaded view models. Can you write an answer, i would mark it as the solution.

Comment: Glad it helped you. I added it to my original answer.